# Order of evaluation of variable

Tags: functions, evaluation, order

I'd like to control the order of evaluation in a multi-variable function.
Example: Suppose I have the function:

```
B[x_, y_] := x + y/x;
```

If I try to evaluate `B[0,0]` I get `Indeterminate` although if I plug in the value of `y` first and then `x` I should get `0`.
Using an intermediate function is not possible in my case.

Is there any way to tell mathematica to plug in the value of `y` first, evaluate the function, then plug the value of `x` ?

Comment: To do what you literally asked: `B[x_, y_] := Module[{xx, yy}, xx + yy/xx /. yy -> y /. xx -> x]`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe easiest to give a definition for your special case, in addition to your general definition.

```
B[x_, y_] := x + y/x
B[0, 0] := 0
```